# nginx : add three extras server in the existing config

Tags: nginx, odoo, letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

This is my nginx config with one server and I 'd like to add three extra server with same settings, certificate and to replace ip address.

```
    # odoo server
upstream odoo15.0 {
  server 192.168.0.101:8069;
}
upstream chat_odoo15.0 {
    server 192.168.0.101:8072;
}

server {
  server_name xxx.be www.xxx.be;

  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo-15.0.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo-15.0.error.log;

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo15.0;
  }
  location /longpolling {
      proxy_pass http://chat_odoo15.0;
  }

  # Specifies the maximum accepted body size of a client request,
  # as indicated by the request header Content-Length.
  client_max_body_size 200m;

  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxx.be/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xxx.be/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = www.xxx.be) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  server_name xxx.be www.xxx.be;
  listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Which is the best way to add extra server on existing configuration?

DO I need to add extra server in the same config file or on separate file (better) ?

```
Server {}
```

Or there is another way?

Best Regards